# DynamoDB put_item() record time > 6hrs?

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I ran the following code, and it stated is executed correctly. It is the result of this [tutorial](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LoadData_PHP.html) that I shortened and rehooked into my project. After it ran the AWS Console said the table had *zero* items. I come back tomorrow and it contains some times. Looking around I found that the console is updated every six hours or so on average. Is there a different way to more immediately check that my data was successfully inserted?

Comment: What code did you run? ;) And where does the information about the supposed six hour delay stem from, could you provide a reference please? I'm having a hard time to believe that actually, especially given the use case for DynamoDB is providing _fast and predictable performance with seamless scalability_ and the AWS Management Console usually showing items in a 'near real time' fashion at least ...

Comment: Right, this confused me as well. 

Go to AWS Console-> DynamoDB, click on a table, and a menu appears below. Click "Details" and near the bottom you'll see a grey line of text:

* Storage size and Item count are not updated in real-time. Instead, they are updated periodically, roughly every six hours.

Which at the time I was using to measure whether or not my inserts had succeeded. Didn't notice the asterisked line till later, and that confused the hell out of me, given what they were claiming. I figured there was something I didn't know.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for the detailed explanation - this doesn't mean the items aren't in the table instantly though, just that this aggregate reporting for the table has a roughly six hours update period (which is admittedly still strange, given that the available CloudWatch metrics periods are much more granular).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

The AWS team has just announced the option to [Explore Your DynamoDB Tables Using the AWS Management Console](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/05/explore-your-dynamodb-tables-using-the-aws-management-console.html) as well:

> You can now view and modify the contents of your DynamoDB tables from
>   within the AWS Management Console. With the addition of this new
>   feature, you can learn by doing -- trying out a number of DynamoDB
>   features without even writing any code. You can create a table, add
>   some items, and see them in the table, all through a very clean and
>   simple user interface.

This is obviously a very convenient addition to the rich client options referenced in my initial answer below, please check out the post itself for a short illustrated *tour to help you get started*.

---

### Initial Answer

The AWS Toolkits for [Eclipse](http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/) and [Visual Studio](http://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/) both allow you to create tables, insert and edit data, initiate table scans, and more, straight from your local development environment (see the introductory post [AWS Toolkits for Eclipse and Visual Studio Now Support DynamoDB](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/01/aws-toolkits-for-eclipse-and-visual-studio-now-support-dynamodb.html)).

The *AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio* seems to provide a particularly fast and thorough UI for all things AWS, but both toolkits can effectively replace the [AWS Management Console](http://aws.amazon.com/console/) for every day usage, if you happen to run one of these IDEs anyway.

Accordingly, I've just added a table and some items, which show up immediately and can likewise be scanned at your fingertips as expected (works with both tookits in a similar fashion).

So depending on your use case this might be all you need.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I installed the Eclipse AWS Toolkit, and I can see the data and it does update, except it seems the downtime for the data becoming available to view is about 5 mins or so. Is that abnormal? Is it usually relatively instantaneous? Maybe Visual Studios is faster?

Comment: @PandemoniumSyndicate: That's strange, it works for me almost instantly in both toolkits actually, i.e. I can insert items, save the changes, execute a scan and the scan result already includes the inserted items, just like one would expect.

Comment: OH! Yup your right, my noob was showing. I thought for some reason eclipse would be continuously updating, silly me. Yup running a scan is what I needed to do. Thanks!